# How to use nestjs interceptor to modify only a part of the body?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have an entity that contains multiple fields but one is called **address**.
I have created and interceptor that works fine to return a geocoded adddress:

**geoloc.interceptor.ts**:

```
import { Injectable, NestInterceptor, ExecutionContext, CallHandler } from    '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable, from, lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
var NodeGeocoder = require('node-geocoder');

var options = {
provider: "opendatafrance",
};
var geocoder = NodeGeocoder(options);

@Injectable()

export class geoLocInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
async intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Promise<Observable<any>>     {

var monaddress = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body.address
const geocodeResult = from(geocoder.geocode(monaddress));
const geocoded = await lastValueFrom(geocodeResult);
context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body = {
address: monaddress,
geocoded: geocoded
}
return next.handle().pipe(
   map(value => {
    return {
      ...value,
      geoCoder: geocoded
    }
  })
  )
  }
  }
```

My problem is that I would like it to take only the "**address**" field and return the body like it was.
I plan to use this interceptor every time I have an "**address**" field to geolocate in a request for whatever entity.

I tried:

```
var monaddress = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().body
```

This does not the job. I do not want to hard-code other fields names.

I am a little bit blocked so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind Regards,